# Pasar datos entre ventanas WPF c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, visual-studio-2017, c#-8.0

Hola buenas tengo lo siguiente en la ventana main :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta ventana main tengo el código que me lleva a la ventana registrar contratos y listado contratos

```
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RegistroContratos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void ListadoContratos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        window2.Show();
    }
}
```

En la ventana Window1 que es la de registrar contratos tengo el código donde registro un contrato (solo esta el numero de contrato ya que es de prueba para poder lograr realizarlo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código,con una coleccion donde guardo los datos de contratos.

```
        ContratoColeccion misContratos = new ContratoColeccion();

        private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contrato contratos = new Contrato();
        contratos.NumeroContrato = int.Parse(txtNumero.Text);

        misContratos.Add(contratos);



    }
```

y por ultimo en la ventana Window2 tengo un dataGrid llamado dgListado donde necesito guardar todos los datos de la coleccion misContratos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo hice de la siguiente manera

```
        private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contrato contratos = new Contrato();
        contratos.NumeroContrato = int.Parse(txtNumero.Text);

        misContratos.Add(contratos);

        Window2 w2 = new Window2();
        w2.dgListado.ItemsSource = misContratos;
        w2.Show();

    }
```

Esto me sirve si quisiera que me habriera la ventana de inmediato, pero cuando llamo la ventana desde el main a listado de contratos me aparece vacia, como podria traspasar estos datos entre ventanas?, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que cuando lo llamas desde el `MainWindow` NO le estás diciendo que el `dgListado.Source` es tu colección (porque no la tienes ahí) y por eso te aparece vacía, por tanto la solución que yo te daría es que declares la colección en el `MainWindow` y trabajes desde ahí, básicamente porque así centralizas el dato y puedes usarlo para otros fines y segundo que definas el `dgListado.Source` en el constructor de la clase.

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ContratoColeccion _misContratos = new ContratoColeccion();
    public ContratoColeccion MisContratos
    {
        get { return _misContratos; }
        set { _misContratos = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RegistroContratos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1(MisContratos);
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void ListadoContratos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2(MisContratos);
        window2.Show();
    }
}
```

**Window1**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    ContratoColeccion misContratos;

    public Window1(ContratoColeccion _misContratos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        misContratos = _misContratos;
    }


    private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contrato contratos = new Contrato();
        contratos.NumeroContrato = int.Parse(txtNumero.Text);
        misContratos.Add(contratos);

        Window2 w2 = new Window2(misContratos);
        w2.Show();
    }
}
```

**Window2**

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2(ContratoColeccion _misContratos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgListado.ItemsSource = _misContratos;
    }
}
```

Y ya con eso debe funcionar como tu quieres.

Ten en cuenta que enviar la colección desde el `MainWindow` hacia las otras ventanas no hace que se cree una copia de ella sino que crea una referencia en la ventana donde se reciba, una especie de "*acceso directo a..*", siempre estarás trabajando sobre la colección en `MainWindow` aún cuando estés en `Window1` o `Window2`, la colección sigue en `MainWindow`.

Comment: Muchas Muchas gracias bro!! has sido el único que entendió y logro ayudarme 2 días para y nada y llegaste a salvarme xD

Comment: De nada, estimado; aprovecho de borrar "MainWindow main" del código de Window2 que se me quedó.